# c# development and project.json

Tags: c#, nuget, csproj

I have read all about Project.json file in ASP.NET 5(vNext).  I have seen tons of people asking if the same changes can be applied to c# projects currently using .csproj/nuget.  I have seen this site https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file that lays out the structure of the project.json, but I cannot find any nuget/visual studio roadmap that states that c# projects will adopt the same project definition file.  It seems like that is the direction they are heading, but was hoping someone could fill me in on more concrete details.  I did see this blurp here: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages#_c35   "Selecting a project.json-file is opening a DNX-project and VSCode will load that project plus the referenced projects". So the new VSCode seems to support this new standard?  I'd appreciate any insight you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "aspnet" name of vnext (ASP.NET 5) is a bit misleading. You can indeed setup new C# class library projects utilizing vnext and the project.json file.

In the new class library project.json, you'll pick which frameworks you wish to target. In beta4 and VS 2015 RC, the default target frameworks are dnxcore50 and dnx451.  dnx451 enabled projects will still still have access to the entire .NET framework just as legacy C# projects always have. Targeting dnxcore will give you access to a much smaller footprint and the ability to modularize your project so you're only incorporating the portions of the .NET Framework you really need.

Comment: I found a great article explaining DNX and .Net Core and am excited about the direction.  http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/dnx.html .  However, why is all of this getting published under asp.net? It seems like it should be agnostic to the .net flavor, if it truely can be applied to c# projects as well.  Thanks for your inisight! I am a Java guy trying to understand these new changes to .net...

Comment: I believe the name is derived from the fact that the primary goal of this upgrade was to unify the core web platform (MVC and WebAPI) and to provide a leaner experience on the web without reliance on the entire .NET stack as has been the case in the past. A majority of the changes in vNext cater specifically to web development, but I agree, the name is still misleading.

Comment: A final question- I currently support c# library projects that need to support .net 4.0.  Can I still use project.json approach to build our projects?